# can gmail contextual Gadget move email to folder based on extractor match?

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

i im trying to build contextual Gadget that moving email based in extractor match
after reading [this](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/gadgets/contextual/) im not sure i can do it . just to be sure . can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done but it will take a server side operation.

1. First you have to get SSO for gadgets working.
2. You need to extract the email Id using one of the pre canned extractors
3. Your app needs enough permissions to access GMail through its manifest file.
4. Send the extracted email Id to your server which can do IMAP manipulation to move to the right folder.

Quite some work....